# Could, would ethernet via usb work on BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu tablet?

Tags: usb, ethernet, tablet, aquaris

I'm considering buying the above mentioned tablet, but just to be sure, I contacted BQ to ask if they can confirm the device recognises an usb ethernet adapter. Unfortunately they didn't provide a positive response. That's a must for me since I often need to test network endpoints, but I wouldn't really want to upgrade my laptop, hoping the tablet could fulfill my needs.

Is there anyone who can share his success or failure in the topic, allowing me to make a final decision?

Also, if it really turns out this doesn't work, what are the reasons behind?

Thank you.

Comment: no definite answer but as can be seen from this post https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336999 it definitely does not work out of the box. Sadly the thread went inactive before posting the results of any of the suggested diagnostic steps.